# Import of DescriptorExtractor and FeatureDetector cannot be resolved in opencv 4.1.0

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, importerror

As I already mentioned in the title, these two imports cannot be resolved in opencv 4.1.0.

```
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor;

import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;
```

This the code:

```
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB); 
DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
```

They are deprecated: https://iopencv.com/docs/cpp-python/3.4.1/javadoc/index.html?deprecated-list.html

But there is no doc on what I should use now.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still stuck at this error. the problem is opencv4.1.0 (and above I think) doesn't have those classes.

Downgrading to opencv3.4.9 fixed it for me!

Comment: SIFT had a patent on it (expired in 2020). that required its implementation to live in the "contrib" set of modules. those aren't ordinarily distributed in binary form.

Answer (score 0):

SIFT patent is expired and included in OpenCV since v4.4 by default, so there is no reason to downgrade.

Just change to your lines of code to (Java)

```
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    SIFT detector = SIFT.create();
    detector.detect(gray, keypoints, mask);
```